# Map Dissapearing After Calling JumpTo (MapboxGL + React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm developing a website that takes in an address from a user and plots a list of nearby locations using MapBoxGL and React. When the user runs the search, an API is called and returns, amongst other things, a center point. This center point is used to call the *jumpTo* function to recenter the map. For the most part things work, however after calling *jumpTo* the map stops displaying (see image below).

When starting the webpage the map looks good:

[image]

However upon calling *jumpTo*, the map disappears:

[image]

I've been stripping away the code to debug, but I'm still at a loss.

During the debugging process I wound up moving the map to what would normally be the parent component. Below is the code with most of the non-map elements stripped away. The map is initialized upon mount. The *runSearch* function calls an API which returns the values (floats) fed to *jumpTo*.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

// Custom elements
import Search from "./components/Search";
import Report from "./components/Report";
//import Map from "./components/Map";

// CSS
import './Style.css';

// Data
import generator_data from './test_data.js'

// Constants
const EVAL_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/eval"

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );
        this.map_ref = React.createRef();
                this.state = {
            query: '',
            proposed_address: '',
            loaded: false,
                        loading: false,
            suggestions: [],
            error_message: '',
            geocoded_value: [],
            generators: [], /* we can replace with generator data to test */
            rank: '',
            map:null,
            map_state: {
            'lng': 43.1939,
            'lat': -71.5724,
            'zoom': 10,
            },
        };  

// Hooks to update the state based on actions in the children components
this.handleSearchBarUpdate = this.handleSearchBarUpdate.bind(this);
this.runSearch = this.runSearch.bind(this);
this.handleMapState = this.handleMapState.bind(this);
}
  // Function called when object is first rendered. This should initialize 
  componentDidMount() { 
    console.log("Mounting mapping")
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibW9vc3RlciIsImEiOiJja2g4Z3FhMHQwaXJ4MzBrOHVjNmtocXB4In0.-oobkw-mOV3-34JwHgrjig';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.map_ref.current,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [this.state.map_state.lat, this.state.map_state.lng],
      zoom: this.state.map_state.zoom,
      
    });

    // Add navigation control (the +/- zoom buttons)
    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), 'top-right');

    map.on('move', () => {

      this.handleMapState(map.getCenter().lng.toFixed(4),
      map.getCenter().lat.toFixed(4),
      map.getZoom().toFixed(2));
    });

  });

  this.setState({map:map})
  };

  // Function called when object is removed
  componentWillUnmount() { 
    this.state.map.remove();
  };

    
    // Handles movement using map controls
    handleMapState(lng, lat, zoom) {
    this.setState({map_state : {"zoom": zoom,
            "lat": lat,
            "lng": lng}})
    }
    
    // Runs search after button click
    async runSearch(event) {
    console.log("Running search for", this.state.query)
    
        this.setState({loading:true});
        axios.get(EVAL_URL + '?address=' + this.state.query).then((response) => {
            // handle success
            console.log(response);
            // jump map here

            this.state.map.jumpTo({ center: [response.data.lat, response.data.lng], zoom: 14})
            this.setState({
            geocoded_value: [response.data.lng, response.data.lat],
            map_state: {"zoom": 14,
                            "lat": response.data.lng,
                            "lng":response.data.lat},
            generators: response.data.locations,
            orphans : response.data.orphans,
            rank: response.data.rank,
            proposed_address: response.data.address_proposed.LOCATION,
            loading:false,
            loaded:true});

          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            this.setState({
            loading:false,
            error_message: error,
            });
          });

}

render() {
        return (
                <div className="map-wrapper">
      <div className='sidebarStyle'>
      <div>
          Longitude: {this.state.map_state.lng} | Latitude: {this.state.map_state.lat} | Zoom: {this.state.map_state.zoom}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='map-container' ref={this.map_ref} />
    </div>
                </div>
        );
    }
}export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

When calling jumpTo, you should pass center array with lng as first, lat as second element, not the other way around.
[Mapbox GL - Camera Options](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/properties/#cameraoptions)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The latitude and longitude are actually misnamed in this version of the code, (they were inverted in the back end this code called)

Comment: Besides it not being inverted latitude and longitude, I don't know what the issue is. In the end I wound up not using React, as it wasn't necessary for my use case.